# Adding functionality to an Entity/Component System

Tags: c#, xna

I'm attempting to write my own Entity/Component System from scratch in C# and I'm stuck on where/how to implement some functionality.

**Edit:** I figured out how where I'm going to add functions like Move() and Jump().

```
public static class Actions
{
    public static void MoveUp(EntityManager entityManager, int EGUID) {}
    public static void MoveDown(EntityManager entityManage, int EGUID {}
}
```

I can add them to a collection like so:

```
KeyboardController kbController = entityManager.GetComponent<KeyboardController(1);
kbController.KeyBindings.Add(Keys.Right, new Dictionary<KeyStateES, Action<EntityManager, int>());
kbController.KeyBindings[Keys.Right].Add(KeyStateES.Held, Actions.MoveUp);
```

And now I'm able to move the Entity around quite easily with key bindings. However, it's still not quite ideal because:

- I can't bind more than one Method to a Key.
- I'm forced to pass the Method Arguments in the InputManager class.

This is a problem because sometimes I'll want a key to perform multiple unrelated tasks and because it seems really silly for my InputManager to be the one passing the arguments for the methods. *Ideally, I would like it so that a KeyDown, KeyHeld, or KeyReleased event is fired and only the Controllers with the particular key(s) bound respond to the event and execute their associated Methods.*

Answer (score 2):

After that you changed `X` and `Y` coordinates o the `Entity` using specific component, you just redraw scene, and `Entity` will appear into the a new position.  Where is actually the problem. ?

You have an `Entity` that is transformed in any possible way with (say) `PositionComponent`, `RotationComponent`, `ScalComponent`, `TextureComponent` and so on, but have  simple `Redraw()` method which renders all `Entites` on the scene in visible frustrum within a *current* state of each one.

Comment: That's what I currently have because Rendering the component is trivial. All you need are Texture and Position components and the Entity will automatically be drawn. Changing the X or Y will reflect on the next draw call. The problem is WHERE to implement the Move() call.

Comment: @Kittoes: if you want single `Move()` call, define it inside class responsible for the rendering. So move will accept generic `Entity` class and `MoveComponent` using which will apply a transformation to the `Entity` and reRender the scene.

Comment: Why define the Move() method in the Render System when Move() doesn't really have anything to do with actual rendering? I was thinking that I COULD have like an "Action System" or "Movement System" but I'm not sure that's the ideal move and it only solves one of the problems. The other is that I don't know how I could go about binding the Move() command to the Up key as described in the OP.

Comment: @Kittoes: Ok, if you architect in a way like having an action library that can be applied on single or collection of `Entities`, it could be done in some (say) `Transform` class, where `Move()` is defined. Add to keyboard bindings an `Action<T>`. In this specific case it will be `Move` fucntion, in others some other function from `Transform` type.

Comment: Ok, I've set up a couple of test methods and I can get them to fire if they have no arguments. The problem is that I want a variety of methods that might have several arguments and I would like all of these methods to be in the same collection. Can I do this?

Comment: @Kittoes: at some level you will need to deverse, you can not uniform **everything**. What I would do in (say) OpneGL engine, is implement Add(), Move().. functions that accepts Matrix3, and acts on that massive [16] accordingly. After render methid just use that matrix to aply transform to associated Entity.

Comment: I don't disagree with you on that point and it's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I just need to add multiple Actions to a particular key bind and I need to be able to pass the arguments to those functions.

Comment: If you want to have a collection off the functions, that can accept different quantity of parameters and different type and may be order of those, I think you need to push abstraction layer one step top. So can define some `FunctionManager` who "knows" for which function how much, in what order and what type parameters need. So push them on global `Stack` and after call the function from the collection. Function pops from the stack values till make it empty and execute. Just an idea. But you should check in terms of performance this approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about a tree of types focused on these high-level behaviors?: i.e. a Jump class would, given an object, know how to make it jump.  Jump might be derived from Move if there is sufficient commonality, etc.  More complex behaviors would then be composed of simpler behaviors heirarchically.

Comment: The problem is not really the specific implementation of Move() or Jump() but where in the code to place this functionality. Creating a Move class or even a Move component doesn't really work. Creating a system that handles any action/movement kind of makes sense but that still only solves the problem of WHERE the function is implemented. For example, the problem of how to bind it to a key still exists.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding -- why does making a Move class not work?  The logic would presumably be implemented in the Move class, which would adjust the location of the entity it is moving after processing whatever business rules there are.  I do this kind of thing all the time, it works well by isolating the abstract logic of operations from the abstract objects they're acting on.   It sounds like you have the same problem, no?

Comment: Because with this architecture it doesn't make any sense to have a Move Class because you only need Move Method. The data that you're acting on already exists in a Position Component Class and you want to directly mess with that component's data. The architecture is focused on Entities made up of various Components and the Components are acted upon with Systems. What system does Move belong in? The answer may not be a system at all. I suppose that I could create a Static Class of Actions containing the logic for things like MoveUp, MoveLeft, etc.

Comment: Yes, it sounds to me like perhaps your top-level taxonomy isn't rich enough.  Entities and Systems is too coarse to allow sufficiently robust categorization of different elements.   (I can only guess here, because I don't have a full understanding of what you're trying to do -- but modeling actions as something distinct from the items they're acting on is a pretty common idiom, and I think it solves your problem if you don't try to force-fit everything into a pre-existing separation between entities and systems.

Comment: I should also mention that I'm not talking about "messing with a component's data".  Certainly the component can protect its position with reasonable rules, while allowing an action component to move it around, yes?   Imagine a video game:  there are often movement classes which know how to make something bounce.  You can have them bounce a ball, or a character in the story, or other elements for which bouncing makes sense.  They don't care what type of object they bounce, and the object has to allow this external class to adjust its position.  Else everything has to have its own bounce logic.

Comment: Well, everything centers around the EntityManager that maintains a list of entities and their components. Components are things such as Position, Velocity, Texture2D, etc. The Rendering System queries the EntityManager and asks for all entities with a Texture2D component and renders them. I've thought about having a Movement System or something but I dunno. I haven't quite figured out a way to organize some things like Movement and whatnot in a way that just "makes sense."

Comment: I almost always end up with a bunch of "operation" classes in any non-trivial application, to structure the complexity of operations.   I think there's a kind of latent thought epidemic in the OO world in this regard -- people learned that objects should include the operations which act on them, and that simplistic concept took over and ran the show.  But like anything, commonality should be factored out.  You don't want every animal to have a "run through hole in fence" method.  That operation is its own class, decomposed into the sub-operations and able to act on abstract objects.

Comment: I couldn't agree more about the OO world because that's pretty much the hardest part about this. I've only been working with C# for about a month now so I'm picking up everything as I go along and most documentation is VERY OO focused. On the other hand, my project is purposefully trying to get away from OO. I suppose Systems are more or less operation classes. Systems are the only parts of the program that actually have methods as Components are nothing more than data. The tricky part is figuring out when I need a new System/where and how to add in operations.